# How to set a picture as activity title that also can be seen in recent apps?

Tags: android, android-activity

I know i can set a picture instead of a simple text as the title of an activity by setting a custom layout as the action bar. But that picture won't appear on that app's card in Recent Apps. There is just the main name of the of the app above the app's card in Recent Apps. Is there any way to set a picture as activity's title that can be seen both in the app and the Recent Apps?
Somthing like this:(this is just a picture , not reality)
[image]

**EDIT**:The text after the Google logo is just a part of the picture. I really don't want to have the simple text and a customized image together.

Comment: are you looking for the AndroidManifest.xml attribute to set the app icon? android:icon="@drawable/your_drawable_name"

Comment: No. Just the title.

Comment: have you seen this in other places? I can't think of any way you can touch that apart from your icon and title

Comment: @SaikCaskey I don't remember exactly but I think I saw it somewhere.